# Google one tap sign-up and automatic sign-in does not return idToken

Tags: php, jquery

I am implementing Google one tap sign-up and automatic sign-in, I followed instructions given in 
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/retrieve-hints

I am getting all the details like

> authDomain, authMethod,​ displayName,​ id and profilePicture

but not getting `idToken`.

Can someone please help in getting this?

Here is my code:

```
const retrievePromise = googleyolo.hint({
    supportedAuthMethods: [
    'googleyolo://id-and-password',
    'https://accounts.google.com'
    ],
    supportedIdTokenProviders: [{
    uri: 'https://accounts.google.com',
    clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    }]
});
retrievePromise.then((credential) => {  
    //here i am not getting credential.idToken                
});
```

Comment: You need to show the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks Hetal for quick response. here is the code I am trying-

Comment: `const retrievePromise = googleyolo.hint({
                supportedAuthMethods: [
                    'googleyolo://id-and-password',
                    'https://accounts.google.com'
                ],
                supportedIdTokenProviders: [{
                        uri: 'https://accounts.google.com',
                        clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
                    }]
            });
            retrievePromise.then((credential) => {
                  //not getting credential.idToekn
             });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977458/google-one-tap-sign-in-does-not-return-idtoken?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google one tap sign-in does not return idToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977458/google-one-tap-sign-in-does-not-return-idtoken)

Comment: Adding port in "Authorized JavaScript origins" at https://console.developers.google.com/ for my project does not resolve it.